# Show that $P_n=p(1-P_{n-1})+(1-p)P_{n-1}$ $n \ge 1$

Tags: probability, induction

Independent trials that result in a success with probability p and a failure with probability 1-p are called Bernoulli trials. Let $P_n$ denote the probability that n Bernoulli trials result in an even number of success (0 being considered an even number). Show that $P_n=p(1-P_{n-1})+(1-p)P_{n-1}$ $n \ge 1$
and use this to prove (by induction) that $P_n=\frac{1+(1-2p)^n}{2}$

So $P_n$ denotes the probability that n Bernoulli trials result in an even number of successes
p = probability of success
p-1 = probability of failure

$P_n=p(1-P_{n-1})+(1-p)P_{n-1}$ $n \ge 1$

I can see that the first part of the equation is the probability of success multiplied by the probability that n-1 trials result in failure, plus the probability of failure multiplied by probability that n-1 trials result in success.

But I don;t know how to show this mathematically..

So I think for the second part, for induction I need to start with the base case, n=1:
$$P_n=p(1-P_{n-1})+(1-p)P_{n-1}$$
$$P_1=p(1-P_{1-1})+(1-p)P_{1-1}$$
$$P_0=p(1-P_{0})+(1-p)P_{0}$$

Then I get kind of stuck, well..$P_0$ is probability of n=0 trials, so would that be 0?
$$P_0=p(1)=0$$

Then for induction, I need to show that n+1 is true right?

Comment: The answers to the question linked by @DilipSarwate seem to explain all the steps of the proof, therefore I'm closing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part: We want to have have an even number of total successes. Lets say that we have performed $n-1$ trials. If we then have an odd number of successes, we will need the last trial to be a success in order for the total number of successes to be even. If the number of successes after $n-1$ trials is already even, then the last event should not be a success. So:

$ P_n=(1-P_{n-1})*p+P_{n-1}*(1-p)$

$P_0=1$ because with $0$ trials you always have $0$ successes (an even number).

For the induction step, assume that it holds for $n-1$. Then:
\begin{align}
P_n
&=(1-P_{n-1})*p+P_{n-1}*(1-p)\\
&=(1-\frac{1}{2}(1+(1-2p)^{n-1}))p+\frac{1}{2}(1+(1-2p)^{n-1})(1-p)\\
&=p-\frac{1}{2}p-\frac{1}{2}p(1-2p)^{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}(1-p)+\frac{1}{2}(1-p)(1-2p)^{n-1}\\
&=p-p+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(1-2p)(1-2p)^{n-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(1+(1-2p)^n).
\end{align}
So we have shown that it holds for $n$ if we assume it holds for $n-1$. (Completing the proof)

Comment: Hey , how to prove the final expression without using pmi , it came in my test and my expression looked no way like this